# How can a BuildBot step be informed that a previous step failed?

Tags: buildbot

In BuildBot, I'd like a step to not execute if a previous step failed.

For instance, in the following class, if `test_package()` fails, I don't want `install()` to execute.

```
class Sage(Project):
    distros = [RHEL7()]
    tests = [SageTest()]

    def test_package(self, f, dist):
        HaltOnFailure=True
        set_properties = {
            'package_file_name': util.Property('package_file_name'),
            'master_dir': dist.master_dir()
        }
        if isinstance(dist, RHEL7):
            f.addStep(steps.Trigger(
                schedulerNames=['sage-rhel7-sage-test'],
                doStepIf=partial(do_step, 'sage-rhel7-sage-test'),
                    waitForFinish=True,
                    set_properties=set_properties))   

    def install(self, f, dist):
        super(Sage, self).install(f, dist)
```

**How can I inform install() that test_package() failed?**

Comment: Build steps have haltOnFailure parameter. If it is True, the entire build will stop immediately.

Comment: Thanks @ayaye: I implemented the haltOnFailure parameter, and it works as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use some common steps parameters: [2.5.9.1. Common Parameters](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#common-parameters/)

For example, **haltOnFailure**:

```
f.addStep(steps.Trigger(
    schedulerNames=['sage-rhel7-sage-test'],
    doStepIf=partial(do_step, 'sage-rhel7-sage-test'),
        waitForFinish=True,
        set_properties=set_properties,
        haltOnFailure=True))
```

You can also try various combinations of doStepIf, hideStepIf, alwaysRun, haltOnFailure, flunkOnWarnings, flunkOnFailure, warnOnWarnings, warnOnFailure for your purposes

But may be it could be better to refactor your code to use install function in separate step and build you solution, as a sequence of steps with a certain conditions.

Answer (score -1):

BuildStep is super class of all build steps so followig kwargs are available to all subclasses

```
name, description, descriptionDone, descriptionSuffix, locks, haltOnFailure,
flunkOnWarnings, flunkOnFailure, warnOnWarnings, warnOnFailure, alwaysRun,
progressMetrics, useProgress, doStepIf, hideStepIf
```

[Reference](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#common-parameters)